# как запустить функцию на PyCuda

Tags: python, numpy, cuda

Нужно запустить функцию написанную на питоне в GPU используя PyCuda.
Когда работаю с массивами, выделяю под них память на видеокарте и дальше могу с ними работать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такое только с функцией, например что бы было так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как показал Саша, код в виде скриншотов это плохо, замените их на текст

Comment: О какой функции идет речь? Решение может отличаться в зависимости от "сложности" функции...

Answer (score 1):

Если функция выполняет простые операции то можно восрользоваться абстракцией [pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html#bonus-abstracting-away-the-complications):

```
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.random.randn(4,4).astype(np.float32))
a_doubled = (2*a_gpu).get()
print(a_doubled)
print(a_gpu)
```

Более сложные функции надо будет реализовывать вставками на языке `C`, как в примере с функцией `doublify(...)`